# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, object

i have encountered this error :

```
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?
```

in this line of code :

```
 listMakans = query.docs.map((m) => Makan.fromSnapshot(m.data()!)).toList();
```

and here is the code for (Makan.fromSnapshot):

```
Makan.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic>? snapshot)
      : id = snapshot!['id'],
        owner = snapshot['owner'],
        category = snapshot['category'],
        hobby = snapshot['hobby'],
        business = snapshot['business'],
        title = snapshot['title'],
        details = snapshot['details'],
        latlng = snapshot['latlng'],
        from = snapshot['from'].toDate(),
        to = snapshot['to'].toDate(),
        created = snapshot['created'].toDate(),
        updated = snapshot['updated'].toDate();
```

i didn't understand where the Object here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
listMakans = query.docs.map((m) => Makan.fromSnapshot(m.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)).toList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `?` from

```
Makan.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic>
```

This `(m.data()!))` is the Object in the error.

Comment: but i tried to delete it, and same problem, the code was work without problems, but after upgrade some plugins, i face this problem

Comment: No, go to your factory Makan.fromSnapshot and remove the question mark.

Comment: Removing the question mark from your method should change the error. It could be from someplace else.